# Can't pull after having a second github account

Tags: github

I have a github account for work. I can't figure out how to create a project/repo outside of the company repo. So, I create another github account and try to push a prototype project, which is not work relative, to the new repo. Now, when I want to push a work project to the work repo, I get

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/<repo-group>/<repo>.git/'
```

I get a look at the config file under .get of the non-work relative project. There isn't any account relative data.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you updated your git config user.name and git config user.email? Also, are you working within the correct master/branch locally prior to push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following, if you haven't:

```
git config user.name = "YOUR NEW USERNAME"
git config user.email = "YOUR NEW EMAIL"
```

Also, make sure your are working in the correct master/branch.

Comment: After running the second command, I am prompted to enter a username and password when I issue a git pull command. I can pull and push afterward. Thanks.